# Theming PreferenceFragmentCompat

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-theme, preferencefragmentcompat

I'm having some troubles setting a theme to `PreferenceFragmentCompat` trying to achieve this:

[image]

**I have these styles set:**

```
<style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/status_bar</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/AppThemeBase.RecordingPreferencesTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeBase.RecordingPreferencesTheme" parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FD0000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#1F6F2B</item>
</style>
```

With this options I can see what I want to achieve in Android Studio layout preview but when it does not have effect when I execute it

**The result when I execute:**

[image]

The only thing it worked so far is using `<item name="android:textColor">#FD0000</item>` that will change the tittle colour but I can't find a way to change the summary colour.

Another question I have is if there is a way to set the theme just for that preference fragment instead of using it in all preferences fragments. Using `android:theme` at the root of the fragment layout isn't working for me :(

**Update:**

As per @Susan question this is how I try to use `android:theme` at the root of the fragment layout I've created this theme based in the main one

```
<style name="RecordingPreferenceTheme" parent="AppThemeBase">
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/AppThemeBase.RecordingPreferencesTheme</item>
</style>
```

And this is the preference layout where I have a fragment which will inflate the `PreferenceFragmentCompat`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/RecordingPreferenceTheme">

<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container_settings"
    android:name="com.example.app.RecordSettingsFragment$RecordPreferences"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And at the root of the layout I'll set `android:theme="@style/RecordingPreferenceTheme"` but it doesn't work, just changes in the main theme set in Activity will have some effect. I've already tried [customize PreferenceFragmentCompat layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36286426/2338932) with same results.

Cheers!!

Comment: Can you share how are you applying `android:theme` in root of the fragment.

Comment: @SusanThapa I've update the question

Comment: it's not possible to just change color for just preference they are hardcoded in its xml layout if your want to do that you have to extend from like specific class like `Preference` and also have to copy its layout xml to your app to have these hardcoded values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this sample project [here](https://github.com/burhankhanzada/CustomPrefenceThemeSample/tree/master) created for your specific case the the only problem for this solution is you have to create your preference from code cant use xml file to inflate and
for those who just want the gist of this solution is that use setLayoutResource() method to set layout and use custom layout i just copied the original layout and hardcoded colors according to @Bhuntupana need

```
val messagesCategory = PreferenceCategory(context).apply {
                layoutResource = R.layout.sample_preference
                key = "messages_category"
                title = getString(R.string.messages_header)
                screen.addPreference(this)
            }
```

**Update**

use layout tag to specify layout resource to use like this

```
        <EditTextPreference
            android:layout="@layout/sample_preference"
            app:key="signature"
            app:title="@string/signature_title"
            app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />
```

`sample_preference.xml` just copy of default layout `preference_material.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight">

    <include layout="@layout/image_frame" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
            android:textColor="#FD0000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/summary"
            style="@style/PreferenceSummaryTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textColor="#1F6F2B" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@android:id/widget_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```